# While Statement in Php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a problem with a while statement in PHP and mysql that I have been trying to figure out for ages, I hope you can help me.

I have a while statement, and inside that I have two if statements. It seems to be working, except it displays the first entry in the array only, multiple times.

```
   <?php
      $i=1;
      while($i<5){

      if ($data_review_list['review'] > 4){ 
           echo "<img src=\"images/good.png\" />\n"; 
      } 

      else{ 
           echo "<img src=\"images/bad.png\"  />\n";
      }
      echo $data_review_user['user_name']; 

      echo $data_review_list['review_msg']; 

      $i++;
     }
     ?>
```

I have put ($i<5) as using ($i!=0) was give me a long list of the first entry. This gives me the first entry 5 times.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the second etc entry to display?

Thank you!

Comment: Whould you post how you query data from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you're updating `$i` each time through the loop, you're never looking at `$data_review_list[$i]`. What does `$data_review_list` look like? Use this code to examine the array:

```
var_dump($data_review_list);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. using the var_dump really helped as I found out that I was just querying the first entry. Changing my fetch_array solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you use mysql or mysqli, but i'll assume you use mysqli for this example. Also let's assume that the query you are querying in mysql has `LIMIT 5` in the end.

```
<?php while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($data['review'] > 4) {
        echo "<img src=\"images/good.png\" />\n"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<img src=\"images/bad.png\"  />\n";
    }

    echo $data['user_name'];
    echo $data['review_msg'];
} ?>
```

This would fetch each of the 5 rows in the while statement.

Comment: Thanks, I am using mysql. Turns out I was fetching the array incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess it should look like this (i am making a few assumptions about your data structure here)

```
<?php
          $i=1;
          while($i<5){

          if ($data_review_list[$i]['review'] > 4){ 
               echo "<img src=\"images/good.png\" />\n"; 
          } 

          else{ 
               echo "<img src=\"images/bad.png\"  />\n";
          }
          echo $data_review_user[$i]['user_name']; 

          echo $data_review_list[$i]['review_msg']; 

          $i++;
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps me in my search for knowledge, but with this problem I was fetching my array incorrectly.